# Getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in fresh magento

Tags: magento, magento2

I have install magneto2 from command line. Now when i start the project from http://localhost/pub/setup, it gives me **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS** error.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.